# can output file be modified to generate blocks of data?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

i am in need of assistance...i have written out code in python to determine all combinations of a set base...however, the output file is enormous depending on the length of the base

is it possible to add code which would enable it to create output files in blocks of say 5gbs which could then be deleted from the total output but still allow the program to continue where it left off? this is my biggest concern...i'm unsure how to approach this without losing what it has already generated but i fear it may not be feasible...any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...thanks.

wendy

current code:

```
    import itertools

    BASE = "stayreadytokeepfromgettingready"
    REPEAT = 4

    def repetitions_for_letter(letter):
      return [letter * count for count in range(1, REPEAT + 1)]

    def repetitions_for_word(word):
      return [repetitions_for_letter(letter) for letter in word]

    def generate(word):
      length = len(word)
      repetitions = repetitions_for_word(word)
      file_object  = open('possibilities.txt', 'w')
      print("Begining generation...")
      for pick_indexes in itertools.product(range(REPEAT),repeat=length):
        parts = [repetitions[idx][pick] for idx, pick  in 
        enumerate(pick_indexes)]
        file_object.write("".join(parts) + "\n")
      file_object.close()
      print("Finished...")
    generate(BASE)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to generate this absurdly huge, almost-no-information-content output anyway? It looks like you're trying to generate about 4 billion billion lines here. This is never going to work. Whatever problem you are trying to solve by doing this, you are not going to solve it this way.

Comment: (4 billion billion isn't quite as absurd as some of the combinatorial explosions people post here, but you're still not going to get it done with a single Python process on a single computer, writing everything to disk.)

Comment: the code presented is only one part of several and it is not being used to solve a problem...it's only purpose is to generate all combinations of said base...the data produced will be handled separately to determine patterns that can be quantified for use in various mediums...chances are slim that the entire output would be completed and i have no desire to store all of the output...

Comment: which is why i am trying to 1) figure out a way to 'pause' the program, 2) take the data output already generated to be processed elsewhere, 3) remove the generated data from the total output file and hopefully 4) 'unpause' the program to continue it's original output...i'm concerned that by removing the generated data from the original output file might disrupt it's functioning and force it to repeat what was removed...if that makes any sense ;p